# When input field is focused and phone virtual key board is opened, button click event is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, windows-phone, iscroll

I am developing mobile application for windows phone 8 using Cordova + Jquery mobile + Iscroll with fixed header and footer.
Every things its working fine.
When input field is focused and phone virtual key board is opened, button click event is not working in application.

```
<form>
    <input id="input1" placeholder="Name" type="text" data-theme="a">
    <input id="input2" placeholder="Address" type="text" data-theme="a">
    <input id="input3" placeholder="Phone" type="text" data-theme="a">
    <fieldset class="ui-grid-a brchbtnmargin">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
            <a data-role="button" data-theme="a" onClick="submitAction();">CANCEL</a>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="a" onClick="cancelAction();">SEARCH</a>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Add more details, nobody knows which button you're talking about.

Comment: My application have search page with three input fields and two buttons(Search,Cancel).When first input focused mobile virtual keyboard is coming then i cant able to click search or cancel buttons.